# failed 2 times due to AM Container for 'attemptid' exited with exitCode: -1000

Tags: java, ubuntu, hadoop2

I am very new in Hadoop (I am using hadoop-2.7.3) and I am trying to do a WordCount example. [Sample from youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6sK3LDY7Pp4)

In this while moving a jar file to hadoop, I am getting an error like

```
'failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1503226867501_0002_000002 exited with exitCode: -1000' I don't have any idea about the issue. Am I missing some settings?
```

[image]

Comment: PLease check Logs by clicking on Logs on displayed UI and update question with actual error from log file.

Comment: There is nothing under log page